# Getting route url from queue returns wrong base

Tags: laravel, queue

When I'm sending a queued mail message from a laravel queue the route urls always return localhost instead of the url set in config app.url. The rest of the site works fine but just urls generated from the queue are wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The `url` in `app.php` is only used when Laravel runs as a console application. Your URLs where created using the domain name the application runs under: `localhost`

You can fix this by only generating a relative URL and then prepend the domain name from the config:

```
$url = Config::get('app.url') . route('route-name', null, false);
```

(The third argument to `route()` is `$absolute = true`. By setting that to false you get a relative URL starting with `/`)